# Install mtpro2 font for TeXLive user

Tags: texlive, visual-studio-code, mtpro2

I'm a Window user, and I'm currently using TeXLive on Visual Studio Code for my LaTeX documents. I recently purchased the `mtpro2` package for a better math font, but what I receive is a file named `mtp2fonts.zip.tpm` and they said it should be use with PCTeX. I do try to install PCTeX but this compiler looks pretty ugly, and I still prefer to use Visual Studio Code.

How can I install `mtpro2` for TeXLive based on Visual Studio Code?

Comment: what is in the zip-file?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm not sure, I think is it the `mtpro2` installer that should be uses with PCTeX. But like I said, I really want to use TeXlive since PCTeX seems outdated.

Comment: Assume that this is a zip file and that you need to unzip it somehow. Try e.g. to remove the .tpm and look if you can open it. (make a back up first ...).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It is .tpm file, I tried to open it with other apps like TextPad but it gives nothing :(